# ElasticSearch only discovering 2 of the 3 nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am working on standing up an ElasticSearch 7.17.1 cluster on vanilla Kubernetes. I have a 3 node K8 cluster and trying to stand up 3 master pods, 3 data pods, and 3 ingest pods for ElasticSearch.

Each K8 deployment spins up the 3 PODS for each Elastic node type (so a total of 9 PODS) successfully. In the ElasticSearch bootstrapping/discovery process only 2 of the 3 nodes are able to fully bootstrap. The other one just sits there just saying:

> "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes"

No matter how many times I spin them down and redeploy...only 2 of the 3 fully bootstrap. Its inconsistent each time as well on which 2 come fully online and which one stall.

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-03-26T14:00:40,468Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-2", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-2}{bmvnsauQRACFwSj7n7GYXA}{T8453ABGTdqKnRednOe5fg}{10.244.218.82}{10.244.218.82:9300}{m}]; discovery will continue using [10.97.85.247:9300] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-2}{bmvnsauQRACFwSj7n7GYXA}{T8453ABGTdqKnRednOe5fg}{10.244.218.82}{10.244.218.82:9300}{m}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }

Here is the K8 YML I am using for the master node deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: elasticstack

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: elasticstack
  name: elasticsearch-master-configmap
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: master
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    cluster.name: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
    node.name: ${NODE_NAME}
    
    network.host: 0.0.0.0

    discovery.seed_hosts:
      - elasticsearch-master.elasticstack.svc.cluster.local
      
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: 
      - elasticsearch-master-0
      - elasticsearch-master-1
      - elasticsearch-master-2

    node.roles: [master]

    xpack.security.enabled: true

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: elasticstack
  name: elasticsearch-master
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: master
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9300
    name: transport
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: master

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: elasticstack
  name: elasticsearch-master
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    role: master
spec:
  serviceName: elastic-master
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
      role: master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
        role: master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch-master
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
          limits:
            memory: 4Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["SYS_CHROOT"]
        env:
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: elasticsearch-master-configmap
      - name: "storage"
        emptyDir:
          medium: ""
      initContainers:
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
```

I am passing the service DNS for the discovery seed hosts and using stateful sets so I can control the POD names and define them for the "cluster.initial_master_nodes:" output

```
 discovery.seed_hosts:
      - elasticsearch-master.elasticstack.svc.cluster.local

cluster.initial_master_nodes: 
      - elasticsearch-master-0
      - elasticsearch-master-1
      - elasticsearch-master-2
```

This happens on all node types: master, data, ingest. Only 2 of the 3 come online for each type.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: from where you are creating the datanodes ? sorry maybe missed config while reading but not getting count of data nodes anywhere and config. is this output of helm or you are using yaml only ?